# How to find the most repeat data in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a TRANSACTION table.
Columns are =

> Personnel_id and Personnel_Name

I want to find the most repetitive data sorting.
How i can do it?
I have tried and I found, the most repetitive result but i can't show personnel_name.

Here is my query ;

```
SELECT PERSONNEL_ID,
       COUNT(PERSONNEL_ID) 
FROM KOMTAS.TRANSACTIONS 
GROUP BY PERSONNEL_ID;
```

And this code gives an error ;

```
    SELECT MAX(R),
           PERSONNEL_ID 
    FROM ( SELECT PERSONNEL_ID,
                  COUNT(PERSONNEL_ID) R 
           FROM KOMTAS.TRANSACTIONS 
           GROUP BY PERSONNEL_ID 
)  ;
```

help please !

Comment: Please provide the error for first query. Which query fires an error? The first or the second?

Comment: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 48 Column: 26

Answer (score 0):

Add a second group by to the second query:

```
SELECT MAX(R),
           PERSONNEL_ID 
    FROM ( SELECT PERSONNEL_ID,
                  COUNT(PERSONNEL_ID) R 
           FROM KOMTAS.TRANSACTIONS 
           GROUP BY PERSONNEL_ID ) 
GROUP BY  PERSONNEL_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. 

SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT PERSONNEL_ID, COUNT(PERSONNEL_ID) as cnt
      FROM KOMTAS.TRANSACTIONS
      GROUP BY PERSONNEL_ID
      ORDER BY COUNT(PERSONNEL_ID) DESC
     ) t
WHERE rownum = 1;

This is true query.
Thanks everybody :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `rownum` and a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT PERSONNEL_ID, COUNT(PERSONNEL_ID) as cnt
      FROM KOMTAS.TRANSACTIONS
      GROUP BY PERSONNEL_ID
      ORDER BY COUNT(PERSONNEL_ID) DESC
     ) t
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`SELECT MAX(cnt) AS c,
           PersonId 
    FROM ( SELECT PersonId,
                  COUNT(PersonId) cnt 
           FROM TRANSACTIONS 
           GROUP BY PersonId ) 
GROUP BY  PersonId 
ORDER BY c DESC;`

Check here [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39f86/6)